# How to rename a group in Contacts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm working on Contacts in Swift. I fetched a list of group by using

```
store.groups(matching: nil)
```

It returns an array of CNGroup.
Now I want to change the group name like this

```
let request = CNSaveRequest()
group.name = name
request.update(group)
```

But the API is used for CNMutableGroup only.

Any suggestion for me ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`group.mutableCopy as! CNMutableGroup`

Comment: That should be `group.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableGroup` I believe, and also should likely be assigned to a new variable which can then be mutated.